# splitting string from listbox items

Tags: c#, listbox

i am listbox to store different strings which user gives as input.
but i want to split those listbox items where i want to have the first word of every item as seperate string and rest as other string.
i am iterating the listbox item as

```
foreach (ListItem item in lstboxColumnList.Items)
            {

                column_name = temp + "\" "+item+"\"";
                temp = column_name + "," + Environment.NewLine;
            }
```

how could i get the splitted string

Comment: Erm, [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming firs word ends with a space, you can use something like below:

```
string firsWord = sentence.SubString(0, sentence.IndexOf(' '));
string remainingSentence = sentence.SubString(sentence.IndexOf(' '), sentence.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your listbox item's format..
but I assumed that your listbox item have at least 2 word and separate by a space..
so, you can do the splitting using substring and index of..

```
string first = sentence.SubString(0, sentence.IndexOf(" "));
string second = sentence.SubString(sentence.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void Test()
    {
        List<string> source = new List<string> {
            "key1 some data",
            "key2 some more data",
            "key3 yada..."};
        Dictionary<string, string> resultDictionary = source.ToDictionary(n => n.Split(' ').First, n => n.Substring(n.IndexOf(' ')));
        List<string> resultStrings = source.Select(n => string.Format("\"{0}\",{1}", n.Split(' ').First, n.Substring(n.IndexOf(' ')))).ToList;
    }
```

resultDictionary is a dictionary with the key set to the first word of each string in the source list.

The second closer matches the requirements in your question that it outputs a list of strings in the format you specified.

EDIT: Apologies, posted in VB first time round.

Answer (score 0):

checkout:

```
 var parts = lstboxColumnList.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Select(i => new { 
                          Part1 = i.Text.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(),
                          Part2 = i.Text.Substring(i.Text.IndexOf(' '))
                       });

 foreach (var part in parts)
 {
     var p1 = part.Part1;
     var p2 = part.Part2;

     // TODO: use p1, p2 in magic code!!
 }
```